# What does & mean in php?

Tags: php, symbols

`&&` is clear in PHP which means AND. But how about just `&`?

For example, what does `$error['type'] & E_FATAL` mean?

Please help me since I am stuck. The code is here:

```
function shut(){

   $error = error_get_last();

   if($error && ($error['type'] & E_FATAL)){
       handler($error['type'], $error['message'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the bitwise AND operator. [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Also, read this: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Also, when directly in front of a variable ( like &$cow) it means that variable is a reference. That's not the case in this example though.

Comment: Yes, but passing/assignment by reference is not what the OP meant.

Comment: yes, I said that too. I was just adding to the information.

Comment: Yeah, but I figured it's best not to overload him/her with information. Baby steps

Comment: JAL's comment was also useful coz I was confused.Thanks

Comment: Thank you Marcel I searched google but could not find the answer.I take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

'&' is Bitwise And operator.
use this link to find more info on this 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php